# Java 11 convertibyte class object to its string representation

Tags: spring-data-jpa, byte, java-11

In order to read some information from a remote source I created a very basic Java class:

```java
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(doNotUseGetters = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
public class RemoteInfo{
    private Long id;
    private byte[] Hash;
}
```

This Java object is then output to controller and prints the following result:

```java
{
 "id": 501,
 "hash": "ZmdyoC0XzealMwIC4fMJkf6Y3Z2mKo4ppn7Z6XyK9W4="
}
```

So we can see the byte[] hash has been converted in its String representation.

The problems I have are:

- If I try to save the hash to a database through an entity (Spring Jpa), the hash representation is not good. Either if the entity hash field is byte[] or String its value in the DDBB is something like `[B@5860fb7b`
- When I save it in a `byte[]` datatype I save the field as it is.
- When I save it in a `String` datatype I save it as `field.toString()`. Also tried `new String(hash_in_byte, Charset.UTF_8)`.

But nothing good happens.

- Even when I receive the hash in `byte[]` before saving the field in the java class (not in the entity/database) I try to print its value either as it is (in `byte[]`) or converting it to `String` I do not see its `String` representation that I can see when printing the java class in the controller.

Any ideas why?